# Return last command executed in bash function

Tags: bash, command-history, bash-functions

Similar to this: [Return last command executed in shell-script](https://superuser.com/questions/453363/return-last-command-executed-in-shell-script).

```
 lastCommand=$(some command here)
```

Is it possible to achieve same result, but instead used inside a bash function,
not a bash script?

**P.S.**

`lastCommand` mean previous command **inside** the function.

Bash 4.2+ solution suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `xtrace`, i.e. `set -x` to do get a history of all commands the shell executes:

setup:

```
xtracefile=$(mktemp)
exec 9>"$xtracefile"
BASH_XTRACEFD=9
set -x
```

then run whatever

```
foo() { echo foo; echo bar; }
foo
```

Now `$xtracefile` should contain the lines

```
+ echo foo
+ echo bar
```

and you can work with that to pick whatever you want. Note that this doesn't clear or clean up the file at any point, it'll grow indefinitely.

If you want to get rid of the `+` signs, assign `PS4=""`.